# cp into destination hierarchy with symbolic link?

Tags: shell-script, symbolic-link, cp

I am trying to write a site deploy script that will copy files like so:

**SOURCE**

```
.
..
src/
html/
```

**DEST**

```
.
..
src/
html/ -> /var/www/ftproot/mysite
```

I want the files in SOURCE `html` to go to DEST `/var/www/ftproot/mysite`.

The script was:

```
cd SOURCE
cp -Rf * DEST
```

Every time I run the script, I get this error:

```
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory 'html' with directory `html'
```

From this, I deduce that `cp` cannot automatically copy files into DEST when DEST has symbolic links.

Notes:

1. Following [the cp manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html), I set `POSIXLY_CORRECT` to 1. This doesn't work.
2. I had to link site `html` to `ftproot/mysite` and not vice versa because the ftp users have weird access modes.
3. This guy [modified](http://verylongnamehere.blogspot.com/2011/10/just-do-it.html) `cp` source code and recompiled it. I don't want to do that to a production server.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: @Dennis Thank you, answers are: 1. yes (start with `l` when `ls -l`) 2. Ubuntu 10.04 server 3. Not safe to assume that

Comment: @Dennis yes you are correct. I edited my post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for any file copying I would suggest `rsync` over `cp` because it has a much finer control what should be copied and how. In your case just give the commands:

```
cd SOURCE
rsync -K -a . DEST
```

The -K option does exactly what you want:
-K, --keep-dirlinks         treat symlinked dir on receiver as dir

Comment: Thank you for this. Exactly what I was looking for after `cp -aPv --remove-destination` started failing when we changed a directory to a symlink in the destination.

Answer (score 3):

Since cp won't copy any directory in SOURCE over any symlink in DEST, one option is to copy those directories separately for each symlink.

#### Approach using [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)

```
cd DEST
cp -Rf SOURCE/* .
find -type l -exec bash -c 'cp -Rf "SOURCE/$0"/* "$0"' {} \;
```

#### Details

- `-type l` restricts find to symlinks.
- `-exec bash -c '...' {} \;` executes `...` in a bash subshell for every found symlink, passing `{}` (the relative path to the symlink) as fitst argument (`$0`).
- `cp -Rf "SOURCE/$0"/* "$0"` copies the contents of the corresponding source directory into the directory the symlink points to.
- The cp command has to be invoked using bash, so the glob (asterisk) will get expanded.

#### Cautions

- I suggest substituting `cp` with `echo` (or `-Rf` with `-Ri`) to make sure find does what you're expecting.
- Without knowing the exact directory structure and the symlinks present in DEST, I can't guarantee that I anticipated all possible oddities.